# How to get time::SteadyTime object as an f64?

Tags: rust

Within the [SteadyTime](https://docs.rs/time/0.1.39/time/struct.SteadyTime.html) object (when println!) I see there are two private variables, tv_sec and tv_nsec, which I would like to access and turn into an f64 value.

Code:

```
println!("{}", time::SteadyTime::now().to_string());
```

Output:

```
SteadyTime(SteadyTime { tv_sec: 30528, tv_nsec: 181374008 })
```

However, I'm not sure how to get those values (other than just filtering from the to_string of the object).

Comment: you can't, please explain what you want to do, not the problem you have **trying** to do what you want. This is not a correct use to get time.

Comment: You can't do this, because, as you know, these are private values.

Find some other way, e.g. a public method.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that `SteadyTime` is stored as seconds and nanoseconds since some predetermined start time is an implementation detail. They don't expose those internals because they're not yours to mess with. The only meaningful thing you can do with a `SteadyClock` is compare it to other `SteadyClock` values.

If you want to get the time *since* a particular moment, you can subtract them.

```
let start = SteadyTime::now();
// ... some work ...
let end = SteadyTime::now();
let duration = end - start;
```

Then `duration` is a [`Duration`](https://docs.rs/time/0.1.39/time/struct.Duration.html) instance, which *does* have methods like `num_seconds` and `num_milliseconds` to get the duration as a numerical value.

Comment: For the OP, note that `SteadyTime` is deprecated and you should use `Instant` instead. It has an elapsed method specifically for this.

Comment: how does this answer the question in any way ?

Comment: "It's impossible but here's the next best thing" seems like a reasonable answer to me.

Comment: question is unclear thus your answer is unclear, I agree the answer is not wrong, but I fail to see how that help much.